# Expressjs on a cPanel environment

Tags: node.js, express, channel

I am trying to build an API with expressjs. Although I was able to run a pretty simple test with basic http like the code below

```
const http = require('http')
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3003;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World! I am your new NodeJS app! \n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

When I am trying the same example with expressjs I get an error Cannot get /node/index.php

the `app.js` code for my express app is below

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3003;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

when I go to terminal and hit `node app.js` I get the console log part but the page can't load.

I also think it is worth mentioning that my `.htaccess` looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3003 / [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3003 /$1 [P,L]
```

I tried adding `DirectoryIndex disabled` in my `.htaccess` but then I get a 500 Internal Server Error error.

Any ideas?

Comment: _"Cannot get /node/index.php"_... what URL are you requesting?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that basic cPanel plan doesn't support node.js applications for some reason (haven't dug deep enough to upderstend why).

What worked for me is getting a [CloudLinux](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/third-party/how-to-purchase-cloudlinux/?_ga=2.208879698.1585571349.1669058635-767483464.1669058635) add-on and running my app from the [software](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/1500000004602-How-to-create-a-NodeJS-application-via-CloudLinux) tab through the provided "Setup Node.js App".

Hope this helps people like me, that are trying to make Express.js work on cPanel.